# How to get id in javascript from php to show data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, summernote

this is my code

```
 <textarea id="summernote<?php echo $u->id ?>" name="isi" placeholder="Tulis di sini" style="width: 100%; height: 100px !important; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;">
```

i put my javascript under textarea

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var id1="#summernote<?php echo $u->id ?>"
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(id1).summernote({
            height: "300px",
            callbacks: {
                onImageUpload: function(image) {
                    uploadImage(image[0]);
                },
                onMediaDelete : function(target) {
                    deleteImage(target[0].src);
                }
            }
        });

        function uploadImage(image) {
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append("image", image);
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('trans/upload_image')?>",
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: data,
                type: "POST",
                success: function(url) {
                    $(id1).summernote("insertImage", url);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }

        function deleteImage(src) {
            $.ajax({
                data: {src : src},
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('trans/delete_image')?>",
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        }

    });
    
</script>
```

I want to show summernote with random id because when i just have one id in my textarea, it's just work for one. So I want to give it random id. But my code doesn't work, i don't know how to implement in javascript.

Comment: Any console errors worth noting (frontend)?

Comment: @GetSet DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost/meskul/assets/summernote/summernote-bs4.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

Use a class instead and loop over all the elements in that class to initialize `summerNote` instances. Also modify the functions as needed to pass in the editor element instance

HTML

```html
<textarea class="editor" id="summernote<?php echo $u->id ?>" ></textarea>
```

JS (abbreviated)

```
$('.editor').each(function(){
     // `this` is the current textarea element
     const $textarea = $(this);

     // init plugin for specific textarea instance
     $textarea.summernote({
            ....
            callbacks: {
                onImageUpload: function(image) {
                    uploadImage($textarea, image[0]);
                              // ^^ which editor element
                },
                ....
            }
        });

});

function uploadImage($testarea, image) {
                    // ^^ textarea object argument
        .....
        $.ajax({
            .....
            success: function(url) {
               $testarea.summernote("insertImage", url);
               // ^^  specific jQuery textarea instance
            },
            .....
        });
```